# SQL Server Audit with dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server-2014, audit

I'm trying to implement database level audit on some tables for tracking the changes. When I activate the audit I see the results in the audit file as seen below.

```
UPDATE "MYDB"."dbo"."MyCompany$Mail Setup" WITH (REPEATABLEREAD, ROWLOCK)  
SET "Description"=@P1 WHERE ("Code"=@P2) AND ("timestamp"<=@P3)
```

As seen from the example, I cannot see the actual parameter values.
The application creating this statement is a well-known Microsoft ERP application and we do not have a chance to change the way it creates sql statements. I believe it's using dynamic sql statements to execute queries on the server.

Is there anyway to achieve this goal or am i missing something here?
(I'm trying to use SQL level auditing because ERP application audit has some limitations.)